# Why is the difference in execution when we assign a function to variable and directly call function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**[Python shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejjDY.png)**

```
def outer():
    def inner(a):
        return a
    return inner
```

Here in the first instance when I call outer(5) it gave me error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: outer() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

When I assign that function to variable and pass a argument to the variable it just returned a value without error i.e

```
f=outer()
f(5)
```

it returned 5

Comment: 1. Don't post links to code 2. Don't post images of code

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the screen instead of linking to a picture of it? Pretty sure you'll get negative votes only because of that...

Comment: Also, do you not see the difference between `outer()(5)` and `outer(5)`?

Comment: It is my first question here so struggling as there are lot of checks while I am trying to ask question and while pasting code too as I was doing it in python shell it is not treating it as a code

Answer (score 1):

The function `outer()` takes no parameters. It defines a local function `inner(a)` and returns *a reference to this function*. This is why your last attempt does not produce an error. By writing

```
f = outer()
f(5)
```

You are essentially assigning the defined function `inner(a)` to f, and then calling it with a parameter 5.

I hope that makes it more clear. Despite this, I don't understand why you would define functions in this way in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`outer()` returns the function `inner()`, so by setting `outer()` to a variable, you are setting that variable to `inner()`, but by seetting `outer` to variable, you are just setting the variable to the function `outer()`